# XmlReader is automatically appending a namespace to all elements, making nice clean linq queries impossible

Tags: c#, xml, linq, gmail

I'm querying the gmail feed using XmlReader and XDocument and I'm running in to trouble with namespaces being automatically appended to all elements.

```
        XmlUrlResolver resolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
        resolver.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.XmlResolver = resolver;

        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/", settings);

        XDocument doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(reader);

        var entries = from x in doc.Elements().First().Elements() where x.Name == "entry" select x;
```

In this case *entries* will be empty because all of the elements have the namespace automatically appended to them. If I change x.Name to x.Name.LocalName or namespace+x.Name then it works.

I'd like to prevent XmlReader from automatically appending namespaces, and query the xml how it was originally sent to me -- without namespaces.

Comment: Note that elements inherit the namespace from the parent if defined as xmlns="..." or empty. To create fully qualified name in Linq to Xml you can do XNamespace ns = "namespace-uri-here"; var el = doc.Elements().First().Elements(ns + "entry")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely that XmlReader "automatically append namespaces", as it normally never modifies content of XML. I think all nodes already have namespaces (if you post sample XML it could be confirmed), so you have to deal with it.

You options: just use namespaces or convert XML by moving nodes to namespace of your choice.

Comment: I was confused because the XML string did not show any namespaces on the child elements, but now I understand that the elements inherit the namespace from the parent, and that the XML in it's serialized form does not necessarily map perfectly to deserialized xml. I'm now ok with manually prepending the namespace for LINQ queries.